# How to loop through commands in HBase shell without invoking the shell each time

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hbase

I have written a script to count how many records have been inserted into 3 individual HBase tables every 2 hours. I'm aware it's shoddy but it works well and i retrieve the desired results.... however I am having to invoke the HBase shell every time it works through the loop.

Is there a way to improve my code so that I don't have to do this to speed things up?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -a hbaseTables=("table1" "table2" "table3");
for i in "${hbaseTables[@]}"
  do
        echo $i >> results.txt
        time=1431925200000
        for ((x=0; x<2; x=x+1))
          do
                hbase shell <<EOF | tail -2 | grep -oE "^[0-9]+" >> results.txt
                scan '$i', {TIMERANGE => [$time,$time+7199999]}
EOF
                time=$time+7200000
          done
    echo ----- >> results.txt
  done
```

Comment: Does it really take long to *start* `hbase shell`?  I'm not familiar with it, but I'd be inclined to guess that the time consuming part is the `scan` operation you perform once it's started.  If that's true, then avoiding multiple launches of `hbase shell` is not really a useful objective, though perhaps it would fall out as a side effect of the solution you're really after.

Comment: Well I can for example invoke the shell and then run multiple commands in the same session. Where as here, I have to start the session, enter command and then exit the session each time. Maybe you're right - maybe it isn't a time killer but it does seem very inefficient.

Comment: If starting a new session each time is indeed fast, then I'm uncertain what your measure of "efficiency" is that calls it inefficient.  Anyway, you could pipe multiple commands into a single `hbase shell`, or dynamically build a script of commands to feed it, but then you'll need a different solution for filtering the output, as `tail -2` will no longer do what you want.

Comment: You can stash all your Hbase shell commands to a single file and pass it as a parameter to a shell script: ./hbase shell ./your_script_file.txt. It's instant.

Answer (score 2):

HBase shell is written in Ruby so you have full access to any Ruby commands.

So for example if I wanted to drop all the tables in a cluster that do not start with the string dev01 I could do this:

```
$ echo 'a=list; a.delete_if{ |t| t=~/dev01.*/}; \
     a.each{ |t| disable t; drop t}; quit;' | hbase shell
```

The above makes a copy of the `list` array into `a`. It then deletes in the copied array, `a`, all the elements that start with `dev01`, and then it loops through the remaining elements in `a` and runs the HBase shell command `disable X` followed by `drop X`.

Answer (score 0):

While working in telecom I was often in need to interact with various CLI tools where they had no any API. For almost all cases like that [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) was a perfect tool. So it can work in style 'expect prompt' then 'write command' then 'collect output'. For advanced scripting there is approach to combine it with TCL language.

For me it once allowed to control distributed setup with several routers available only by SSH. So it is definitely approach you can use, the question is if it is not too powerful.

Other alternative is to just prepare script for HBase shell into external file and then execute it with output processing. Probebly it is the best combination of efforts and result.